# Chrome adding extra spaces in between words?

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome

Using wordpress.org, only happening in Chrome.

```
Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. - in backend of WP...
```

Renders this...

```
Aenean   lacinia  bibendum nulla sed consectetur.
```

There aren't additional   or padding, etc. Just one space that is at least double wide. Seems to fix when I delete the space (so there is none), then space again in the areas that are being affected.

Please help!!

Comment: Can you give your site url please?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the text formatting is set to 'justifyfull'. In the post editor just select the text then change is justification to 'left'.